# There's no $f$ such that $f(n^{+}) \in f(n)$

Tags: set-theory

Let $\omega$ the natural numbers. I've tried show there's no $f: \omega \rightarrow x$, such that $f(n^{+}) \in f(n)$, where $x$ is just a set, $x \neq \emptyset$ and notation $v^{+} = v\cup\{v\}$, for any set.

My attempt:

There is a hint, and it's use the the axiom of regularity, i.e., for all non-empty set $z$, exist $y \in z$, such that $y\cap z = \emptyset$. My idea was assume the existence of $f$, so by the axiom of pairing and induction we can define a family of sets $U_{n} = \{f(0), \cdots, f(n) \}$, then find a contradiction with the fact $U_n-\{f(0)\} \subset U_{n^{+}}-\{f(0)\} \subset \bigcup U_n$, contraction provide by the consequences of regularity (e.g. if y in x, then x is not in y), but I couldn't conclude anything about $f$ and the $U_n$'s.

The context is ZF with $\omega$ well-ordering.

Thank you.

Comment: In more structuralist language, I think you're basically saying: Let $X$ denote a set, and $W$ denote a (strictly) well-founded relation on $X$. Show that there's no $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},W(f(n^+),f(n)).$ Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

That approach may work, but I'm not seeing how. A better way to go: consider the set $\{f(n) : n \in \omega\}$. This set exists by Replacement (we replaced all of the elements of $\omega$ using $f$). Suppose it has the element $y$ required by Regularity. $y$ would have to be $f(n)$ for some $n$. What can you say about $f(n^+)$?

Comment: Say that the Regularity condition (empty intersection) is not verified. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need Replacement if $f$ exists, since that means it is a set.